# How to add to a <ul> using Angularjs - upon click of button/user input entry?

Tags: html, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

Pls refer to my jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/sash2507/9g5c3f49/1/

I need a way to take the user input (filename) from the input box - and add it as a list item to the `<ul>`. I thought a .push directive would work and an ng-bind on the `<ul>` of that empty array variable? It isn't working. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

///////////HTML/////////////

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
        <script    `enter code here`src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="JS/main.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="MyModule">
        <div ng-controller="MyController as ctrl">
        <h2>Folders</h2>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="ctrl.isBoxChecked">Expand All
            <div ng-show="ctrl.isBoxChecked">
                <h2>Folder 1</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>File 1.1</li>
                    <li>File 1.2</li>
                    <li>File 1.3</li>
                </ul>

                <h2>Folder 2</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>File 2.1</li>
                    <li>File 2.2</li>
                    <li>File 2.3</li>
                </ul>

                <h2>Folder 3</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>File 3.1</li>
                    <li>File 3.2</li>
                    <li>File 3.3</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div>
                <span id="fileInputBox">File Name: 
                    <input type="text" ng-model="someFileName" `enter code here`placeholder="enter a file name" >
                    <button ng-click="ctrl.onUserClick">Add to list</button>
                </span>
            </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

//////////////JS////////////

```
    var myMod = angular.module("MyModule", []);
    myMod.controller("MyController", function() {
        var self = this;

        // Makes checkbox unchecked upon page load
        self.isBoxChecked = false;

        // onUserClick fn makes value true for ng-show
        self.onUserClick = function() {
            self.isBoxChecked = !self.isBoxChecked;
            self.someFileName = self.fileNamesInList;
            self.fileNamesInList.push({
                self.someFileName
            })
        };

        // Empty array for file names
        self.fileNamesInList = [];

    });
```

///////CSS//////////////

```css
    #fileInputBox {
        margin-left: 300px;
        position: fixed;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in:

```
self.fileNamesInList.push({
 self.someFileName
})
```

You are pushing a object but you did not specify the name of the property

Answer (score 0):

@Saloni Sharma First of all make it correct

```
<script    `enter code here`src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script> to 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
```

by this your angular js is not defining. and then use $scope in your controller and new array to push the names,try the below code it is working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var myMod = angular.module("MyModule", []);
myMod.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
    var self = this;

    // Makes checkbox unchecked upon page load
    self.isBoxChecked = false;

    // onUserClick fn makes value true for ng-show
    $scope.pusharr=[]; //new array to push names
    $scope.someFileName="";
    $scope.pushme = function(name) {
        $scope.pusharr.push(name);
        $scope.someFileName="";

    };

    // Empty array for file names
    self.fileNamesInList = [];

});

    </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="MyModule">
    <div ng-controller="MyController as ctrl">
    <h2>Folders</h2>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="ctrl.isBoxChecked">Expand All
        <div ng-show="ctrl.isBoxChecked">
            <h2>Folder 1</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>File 1.1</li>
                <li>File 1.2</li>
                <li>File 1.3</li>
            </ul>

            <h2>Folder 2</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>File 2.1</li>
                <li>File 2.2</li>
                <li>File 2.3</li>
            </ul>

            <h2>Folder 3</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>File 3.1</li>
                <li>File 3.2</li>
                <li>File 3.3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div>
            <span id="fileInputBox">File Name: 
                <input type="text" ng-model="someFileName" `enter code here`placeholder="enter a file name" >
                <button ng-click="pushme(someFileName)">Add to list</button>
            </span>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="name in pusharr">{{name}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I focused to push concept only in that try this.